# Override a static method in a TypeScript subclass

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to override `create` static method in the `Bar` class, but TypeScript gives me the following error:

```
TS2417: Class static side 'typeof Bar' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Foo'.
The types returned by 'create(...)' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'Foo<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'InstanceType<M>'.
```

This is confusing, since `Bar`'s signature is the same as the one from `Foo`.

Code ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNA3gWAFDWmHgDsIAXAJwFdgz4KAKAByoCMQBLYaJi+JiAC5oKAJRYAvnjwFyYMl0IUApvOWoANNACy0ZQA8yy4gBMYZAJ5Nl8AGZxEqNGgZkAFhyE6tvfl7FYMgTQKmRUFMTQxMoA7tDunsx8AuKQ0ACSpGRgxMDKKFbq2mhBUrhleKCQMABCYBROeobGZg7I6IH4PGyc3Kz1DOKYFV1yCtzAKmpOSX7CAThdBKHhkRBU1hQAdJOqRrMppXgSQA)):

```
class Foo<T> {
  constructor(public props: T) {}

  static create<T, M extends typeof Foo<T>>(this: M, props: T) {
    return new this(props) as InstanceType<M>
  }
}

class Bar<T> extends Foo<T> {
  public bar() {}

  static create<T>(props: T) {
    return super.create(props)
  }
}
```

Comment: `Bar`'s signature is not the same as `Foo`'s. `Foo`'s promises to work for all subclasses of `Bar`, while `Bar`'s only works for one particular subclass (itself). That fails Liskov substitution and hence fails to compile.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Sorry, I'm not getting it. All of the arguments, supplied to `Bar.create` will work with `Foo.create`. Can you give a practical example, please?

Comment: It's the explicit `this` argument that's causing the problem. By making `this` have an explicit type, you've made that a part of your function's signature and forced subclasses to obey that constraint. The fact that `props` has a matching type isn't good enough anymore.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo but `this` type of `Bar` obeys constraint `extends typeof Foo<T>` since it's a subclass of `Foo`

Comment: Generics are a universal (or 'for all') relation, not an existential one. If you write a function with a generic argument `M extends typeof Foo<T>`, it has to work for *all* such `M`, not just one of your choice. Yes, `typeof Bar` is one example of an `M` that extends `typeof Foo`, but there are infinitely many others.

Comment: What's the question here?  Is it "how do I fix it?" If so then I'd suggest using an identical signature like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbEn8N) (and if that doesn't work for your use case then we'd need to see a [mre] that shows why).  If it's "why is the compiler complaining"? If so then the answer is that it can't verify that the subclass satisfies the hairy polymorphic constraints you've placed (presumably to work around lack of static `this` types); even if you implemented it correctly, the compiler can't see it.